# SQL Trigger for Delete value into a table and Update the deleted value into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to delete the value from one table and update the deleted values into another table using sql trigger

Answer (score 0):

Create a delete trigger on the table from which value is going to be deleted,inside the trigger update the new table by using deleted keyword for MSsql or OLD keyword for mysql.Those are called magic tables check on them.

Comment: IF NEW.deleted = 0 THEN
UPDATE project_account SET investonproject = investonproject + NEW.amount
WHERE id=OLD.account_id
ELSE
UPDATE project_account SET investonproject = investonproject - OLD.amount 
WHERE id=OLD.account_id
 END IF;                                                                                                                             It shows error in else condition

Comment: IF OLD.deleted = 0 THEN
UPDATE project_account SET investonproject = investonproject + NEW.amount
WHERE id=OLD.account_id
ELSEIF NEW.deleted = 1 THEN
UPDATE project_account SET investonproject = investonproject - OLD.amount 
WHERE id=OLD.account_id
END IF;                                     It shows error in Line 5

Comment: terminate each update statement with semicolon.Also could i have your table structure.